How configure nginx.conf with AWS ECS Service connect(each services on same cluster)?
In my cluster, I have two services: one for nginx and one for the Next.js client. The Next.js service is on a private subnet, while the nginx service is on a public subnet. In the AWS console, I enabled service connect when defining the services (Next.js service is set as ‘client and server’ and nginx service as ‘client side only’) and I defined the DNS as ‘nextjs-service’. Then, in the nginx.conf file, I configured it like this:
events {}

http {
    upstream nextjs {
        server nextjs-service:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name nextjs-service;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nextjs;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            # Increase buffer sizes
            proxy_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_buffers 4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        }
    }
}


However, the health check of the target group is not passing, and the nginx service is failing to connect to the Next.js service.
# next.js task definition json file
{
  "family": "girmanager-admin",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::************:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nextjs",
      "image": "************.dkr.ecr.**-********-*.amazonaws.com/girmanager-admin:latest",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "name": "nextjs-port"
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/nextjs-service",
          "awslogs-region": "**-********-*",
          "awslogs-create-group": "true",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "essential": true,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "NODE_ENV",
          "value": "production"
        },
        {
          "name": "PORT",
          "value": "3000"
        },
        {
          "name": "API_SERVER_BASE_URL",
          "value": "http://nextjs-service:3000"
        },
        {
          "name": "HOSTNAME",
          "value": "nextjs-service"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
  "cpu": "1024",
  "memory": "2048"
}

# nginx task definition json file
{
  "family": "girmanager-nginx",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::***********:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "************.dkr.ecr.**-********-*.amazonaws.com/girmanager-nginx:latest",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "name": "nginx-port"
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/nginx-service",
          "awslogs-region": "**-********-*",
          "awslogs-create-group": "true",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "essential": true
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
  "cpu": "256",
  "memory": "512"
}


#!/bin/bash

# Create or update ECS services
echo "Creating or updating Next.js service..."
if aws ecs describe-services --cluster girmanager-admin --services nextjs-service --query "services[0].status" --output text | grep -q "ACTIVE"; then
    aws ecs update-service --cluster girmanager-admin --service nextjs-service --task-definition $LATEST_NEXTJS_REVISION > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Next.js service updated successfully."
else
    aws ecs create-service --cluster girmanager-admin --service-name nextjs-service --task-definition $LATEST_NEXTJS_REVISION \
        --desired-count 1 \
        --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[$PRIVATE_SUBNETS],securityGroups=[$SECURITY_GROUP_ID]}" \
        --service-connect-configuration "enabled=true,services=[{portName=nextjs-port,discoveryName=nextjs,clientAliases=[{port=3000}]}]" > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Next.js service created successfully."
fi

echo "Creating or updating Nginx service..."
if aws ecs describe-services --cluster girmanager-admin --services nginx-service --query "services[0].status" --output text | grep -q "ACTIVE"; then
    aws ecs update-service --cluster girmanager-admin --service nginx-service --task-definition $LATEST_NGINX_REVISION > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Nginx service updated successfully."
else
    aws ecs create-service --cluster girmanager-admin --service-name nginx-service --task-definition $LATEST_NGINX_REVISION \
        --desired-count 1 \
        --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[$PUBLIC_SUBNETS],securityGroups=[$SECURITY_GROUP_ID]}" \
        --service-connect-configuration "enabled=true,services=[{portName=nginx-port,discoveryName=nginx,clientAliases=[{port=80}]}]" > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Nginx service created successfully."
fi

After creating an ECS cluster, I set up nginx and nextjs services, placing the nginx service in the public subnet and the nextjs service in the private subnet. I wanted to connect to the nextjs service through the ALB DNS by linking an ALB to the nginx service. Initially, I considered building only the nextjs service and placing the ALB in the public subnet without the nginx service. However, I wasn’t sure how to make the nextjs service accessible from the outside when it was hosted with the internal IP of the Docker container, which led me to the current setup.
